# Edebug: instrument function without setting breakpoint?

Tags: elisp, edebug

If I have a buffer with the contents

```el
(defun foo()
  (interactive)
  (bar)
  (message "foo"))

(defun bar()
  (interactive)
  (message "bar"))
```

...and call `eval-buffer` with `edebug-all-defs` set to `t`, then both calls to `foo` and `bar` directly throw me into `edebug-mode` (despite not having set any breakpoints).

On the other hand, if I set `edebug-all-defs` to `nil`, evaluate the buffer with `eval-buffer` and then manually instrument the `foo` definition with `edebug-eval-defun` (`C-u C-M-x`) things work a little better: calling `foo` invokes the debugger, and calling `bar` does not. However, when stepping through `foo`, I'm now unable to step *into* the `bar` function (presumably because it hasn't been instrumented, the error is `` Don't know where `bar' is defined ``. Stepping *over* the call to `bar` works just fine and gives the correct result).

Is there a way to instrument all functions in a buffer *without* making them breakpoints at the same time?

Emacs 24.4.1 on Debian Jessie. Running with `-Q` does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure you can't step into a function which wasn't instrumented? Because if by stepping you mean executing the function one expression at a time, as in by pressing `SPC` while in debug mode, then it works for me without instrumenting. All I need is to enter some instrumented function, which will call the function in question.

Comment: The statements you describe are not what I get. If I do `C-u C-M-x` on a function, calling that function always invokes edebug, regardless of whether I've used `edebug-on-entry`.

Comment: @Malabarba: then your emacs behaves differently. What version are you using?

Comment: @wvxvw: yes, I'm sure.

Comment: Myabe this is the problem of a function not being associated with a file... i.e. Emacs stores the location of a function source in some symbol property of the function name, but maybe if you define it in a buffer not associated with a file, then it doesn't know how to find it? Could you try doing the same thing but instead save the function definition in an actual file?

Comment: @wvxvw:  The problem indeed goes away if use a file-backed buffer instead of `*scratch*`. How did you think of that? Please turn your comment into an answer I can accept :-).

Comment: Posted with a detailed comment ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it appears that the problem in this case was related to the function being declared in a buffer which doesn't have a file associated with it, thus Emacs was unable to locate the definition.  Here's how I discovered this:

1. I started by looking into the definition of `edebug-step-in` (I figured out this is the function called in debug mode when I press <kbd>i</kbd> for stepping in by inspecting the help page for debug mode (available through pressing <kbd>?</kbd> while in debug mode).
2. Thus I found `edebug-instrument-callee`, then `edebug-instrument-function`, then `find-function-noselect`, then `find-function-search-for-symbol`, then `find-function-library` and finally, `symbol-file`.
3. `symbol-file` is the same function used to locate the references whenever you see those references highlighted in a help buffer, or when you call `describe-function` (<kbd>C-h f</kbd>).
4. Then I tried to copy what `symbol-file` does (roughly, just to convince myself that I am on the right track):

   ```
   (defun my/defined-in-file (s)
     (car 
      (cl-find-if
       (lambda (x)
         (cl-some
          (lambda (y) (eql s (if (symbolp y) y (cdr y))))
          (cdr x)))
       load-history)))

   (my/defined-in-file 'symbol-file)
   "/usr/local/share/emacs/25.0.50/lisp/subr.elc"
   ```

   The results turned out positive.
5. When I tried to do the same thing with the functions, which were declared in `*scratch*` buffer, I've got no results.
6. Hence, the conclusion: the automatic instrumentation during "step-in" operation must have failed due to Emacs not being able to locate the source file for the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can step into `bar` (or any function call) with no previous preparation.

1. `eval-buffer` (not necessary if everything's already defined).
2. Invoke `C-u C-M-x` on `foo` to instrument it.
3. Ivoke `M-x foo` and you'll be taken immediately into edebug, with point right before the `(bar)` expression.
4. In edebug, with point right before a function call, you can hit `i` to instrument and step into that function, even if it was not prevously instrumented.

The `i` key is described [in this manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Jumping.html#Jumping). More keys are described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug-Execution-Modes.html#Edebug-Execution-Modes) and [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug-Misc.html#Edebug-Misc).
I also have a [couple of](http://endlessparentheses.com/debugging-elisp-part-2-advanced-topics.html) [blog posts](http://endlessparentheses.com/debugging-emacs-lisp-part-1-earn-your-independence.html) describing the keys I find most useful.

Comment: Sounds great, but does not work. Pressing "i" in step 4 gives a "Don't know where `bar' is defined" error.  Emacs 24.4.1.

Comment: @Nikratio did you eval-buffer first?

Comment: Yes. Without `eval-buffer`, the error message is .. nothing. Instead emacs just hangs when I press `i`. Interesting.

Comment: @Nikratio are you trying all this with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Yes, this also happens with `emacs -Q`

Comment: @Nikratio Ok, I do too. I think I see the problem. Are you doing that on the `*scratch*` buffer or some other non-file buffer? That's why it fails for me. If I do it on a proper file buffer then it works.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to debug stuff with [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) instead of Edebug, possibly using Edebug for setup.

For me, the biggest advantage is that I can keep the debug state around, without worrying that if I mistype something in Edebug, all the debug context that I've worked on for 10 minutes will vanish and I would have to start from scratch. It's also great for setting test cases, sinks / mocks etc.

### Stepping in and stepping through

You don't need to instrument anything, just press <kbd>xj</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-j</kbd> to step in.  All the debug state will be kept as global variables. Then just use <kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd> to
step.

### Using Edebug for setup

If you're debugging a first function call, but actually are interested in how it affects a second function several layers down, just edebug the second function with <kbd>xe</kbd>, eval the first function call with <kbd>e</kbd>, and you'll end up in Edebug.  Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to exit in Edebug, while storing the arguments of the current function in global vars. Now, you can continue as before.

If you expect the arguments to be modified in the debug process and don't wish to repeat the setup above, just generate a set of `setq` statements in `*scratch*`, so that you can reset them easily.

Starting from:

```cl
|(setq foo)
```

with `foo` e.g. having the value `42`, by typing <kbd>2mE</kbd> you get:

```cl
(setq foo
      42|)
```

- <kbd>2m</kbd>: mark second element of sexp
- <kbd>E</kbd>: eval current selection (list or region) and insert the result

The standard equivalent for <kbd>2mE</kbd> would be: <kbd>M-f M-f SPC C-u C-x C-e</kbd>.